# Focus DataGridRow after ItemsSourceUpdated

Tags: c#, wpf

I do have a timer based update of `DataGrid.ItemsSource`.
In View I have subscribed an own event called `ViewModel_ItemsSourceChanged`.

After this update I am not able to focus the Grid.

```
    private void ViewModel_ItemsSourceChanged(object sender, ItemsSourceChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Index > 0)
        {
            MainDataGrid.SelectedIndex = e.Index;
            MainDataGrid.SelectedItem = MainDataGrid.Items[e.Index];
        }

        // pretty fine here
        var dataGridRow = (DataGridRow)MainDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(MainDataGrid.SelectedItem);

        if (dataGridRow != null)
        {
            MainDataGrid.Focus();
            dataGridRow.Focus();
            dataGridRow.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }
    }
```

I tried lot of answers, SNOOPS, `FocusManager`, `Keyboard.Focus(MainDataGrid)` , etc.
Nothing works for me.

Do you have any ideas how to get the focus on the MainDataGrid/SelectedItems row ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that something in the application stole the focus after my code execution.

I solved it by using a timer which takes the focus back on the DataGrid.